# ASP.NET Edit every record in Datalist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I currently have a `DataList` control, with the `ItemTemplate` and `EditItemTemplate` defined.

```
<asp:DataList ID="UserMatrixDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns = "1" CellSpacing = "6" RepeatLayout="Table" BorderWidth="5">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="table">
            <col width="130">
            <col width="800">
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <strong>Level</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLevel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Level")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <table class="table">
            col width="130">
            <col width="800">
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <strong>Level</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtLevel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Level")%>'></asp:Textbox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

After I do a `Databind()`, may I ask how can I set all records in the datalist to EditMode?